# partial differentiation for Logisitc Regression loss formulation?

Tags: calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I'm trying to learn gradient descent for Logistic Regression. So, this is my logistic loss function,

$$argmin\;\;\sum_{i=1}^nlog(1+exp^{-(y_iw^T.x_I)})$$

I've calculated the partial derivative of $\frac{\partial L}{\partial W}$ for the above function to use in gradient descent update step. I just wanted to know if it's correct?

$$\rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial w}=\;\;\sum_{i=1}^nlog(1+exp^{-(y_iw^T.x_I)})$$
$$\rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial w}=\;\;\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial w} 1 + exp^{-(y_iw^Tx_i)}}{1 + exp^{-(y_iw^Tx_i)}}$$
$$\rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial w}=\;\;\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{0 + exp^{-(y_iw^Tx_i)}(-x_iy_i)}{1 + exp^{-(y_iw^Tx_i)}}$$
$$\rightarrow\;\;\sum_{i=1}^n\;-exp^{-(y_iw^Tx_i)}(x_iy_i)\;\frac{-exp^{-(y_iw^Tx_i)}(x_iy_i)}{exp^{-(y_iw^Tx_i)}}$$
$$\rightarrow\;\;\sum_{i=1}^n\;-exp^{-(y_iw^Tx_i)}(x_iy_i)\;-(x_iy_i)$$
$$\rightarrow\;\;\sum_{i=1}^n\;-(exp^{-(y_iw^Tx_i)}(x_iy_i)\;+(x_iy_i))$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w}=\;\;\sum_{i=1}^n\;-(x_iy_i)\;(exp^{-(y_iw^Tx_i)}+1)$$

Gradient update:
w_prev = w_prev - learning_rate * $\frac{\partial L}{\partial W}_{w_1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L(w) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log\left( 1+\exp(-y_iw^Tx_i)\right)$$

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_j} &= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{0+\exp(-y_iw^Tx_i)\frac{\partial }{\partial w_j}(-y_iw^Tx_i)}{\left( 1+\exp(-y_iw^Tx_i)\right)} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\exp(-y_iw^Tx_i)}{\left( 1+\exp(-y_iw^Tx_i)\right)} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial w_j}(-y_iw^Tx_i)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\exp(-y_iw^Tx_i)}{\left( 1+\exp(-y_iw^Tx_i)\right)} \cdot (-y_ix_{ij})\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \left( 1+\exp(y_iw^Tx_i)\right)^{-1} \cdot (-y_ix_{ij})\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! Can you also explain how did you arrive from $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\exp(-y_iw^Tx_i)}{\left( 1+\exp(-y_iw^Tx_i)\right)} \cdot (-y_ix_{ij})$ to $\sum_{i=1}^n \left( 1+\exp(y_iw^Tx_i)\right)^{-1} \cdot (-y_ix_{ij})$?

Comment: I just multiply the numerator and denominator by $\exp(y_iw^Tx_i)$

Comment: Oops! Got it. Thanks